# Merging tables and concatenate strings in specific table

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two different tables into one table.
The first table is Pandas data frame that contains information about the period years from 2000 until 2005 or six observations:

```
time_horizon=pd.DataFrame(range(2000,2005+1))
```

Now I want to concatenate this text 'WT' with the previous ***time_horizon***

```
time_horizon+str('WT')
```

After this next step should be to add specific values for this observation

```
values=pd.DataFrame(range(1,7))
```

In the end, I need to have a data frame as data frame showed on the pic below

[image]

The second step for concatenation not works for me so I can't implement the third step and make this table.

So can anybody help me how to make this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution to the second step that failed for you.

```
str('WT')+(time_horizon).astype(str)
```

```
0
0   WT2000
1   WT2001
2   WT2002
3   WT2003
4   WT2004
5   WT2005
```

One way to solve it is

```
# create a df, with columns only
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=range(2000,2005+1)).add_prefix('WT')

# fill first column with range of values
df.iloc[:,0]= range(1,7)

# forward fill across rows
df.ffill(axis=1)
```

```
    WT2000  WT2001  WT2002  WT2003  WT2004  WT2005
0   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   2   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   3   3   3   3   3
3   4   4   4   4   4   4
4   5   5   5   5   5   5
5   6   6   6   6   6   6
```